# Unable to get correct rounding mode code for `vrndscalepd`

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, nasm, avx512

I am calling `vrndscalepd` to round a ZMM register.  The register to round is:

```
{3.9304247359239284, 0.85804618270500566, 1.899940908279022,  
 1.5554455222287524, 9.1150061014624413,  9.3562881423859334,  
 1.3206387781690712, 9.0367010342260201}
```

I want to round each of these to two digits past the decimal, but none of the rounding mode codes I have tried do that:

```
vrndscalepd zmm9{k1}{z},zmm8,32 ; 00100000
{4, 0.75, 2, 1.5, 9, 9.25, 1.25, 9}

vrndscalepd zmm9{k1}{z},zmm8,33 ; 00100001
{3.75, 0.75, 1.75, 1.5, 9, 9.25, 1.25, 9}

vrndscalepd zmm9{k1}{z},zmm8,34 ; 00100010
{4, 1, 2, 1.75, 9.25, 9.5, 1.5, 9.25}

vrndscalepd zmm9{k1}{z},zmm8,35 ; 00100011
{3.75, 0.75, 1.75, 1.5, 9, 9.25, 1.25, 9}

vrndscalepd zmm9{k1}{z},zmm8,41 ; 00110001
{3.75, 0.75, 1.75, 1.5, 9, 9.25, 1.25, 9}

vrndscalepd zmm9{k1}{z},zmm8,42 ; 00110010
{4, 1, 2, 1.75, 9.25, 9.5, 1.5, 9.25}
```

None of those does what I want. Is there another rounding mode that I have missed, and that will round to two places past the decimal without rounding to the nearest even multiple of 0.25, on AVX512? Is there another instruction that will do what I want using ZMM registers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, AVX-512 uses binary floating point, not decimal.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

`3.93` isn't exactly representable as a float or double so it's literally impossible for any sequence of instructions to create a bit-pattern that represents it.  (https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

You could of course do something that gets a value that's close, like `3.9300000667572021484375f`, but it's not as simple as zeroing some low bits of the mantissa like `vrndscaleps/pd` does.  That will necessarily produce a value that's representable as a fraction with a power-of-2 denominator (because all FP values are like that.)  A "more round" binary FP value will have a smaller denominator; with 2 bits after the radix point, the denominator will be 4, so `.0`, `.25`, `.5`, or `.75` are the only possibilites.

The normal way to round to 2 decimal digits is I think to multiply by 100.0, round to nearest integer, multiply by `1.0/100`.  I don't know if there's anything more efficient / clever.  (Note that `1.0/100` isn't exactly representable, so dividing by `100.0` could be more precise.)

Comment: Re “Note that `1.0/100` isn't exactly representable, so dividing by `100.0` could be more precise”: There is going to be a rounding error when multiplying by 100 and another when dividing, so dividing by 100 instead of multiplying by `1.0/100` is not going to give a completely correct rounding function. I expect it could produce some results that are off by more than .01 (the multiplication rounds up, e.g., producing 91.5 when 91.4999…5 would have been desired, and later the division also rounds up, producing something a bit over .92, so the final result is more than .01 away from .91).

Comment: BTW, `1.0/100` is in code font, so it represents something a program does, so its result is representable, as the result is whatever the program produces. For notation in these situations, I use plain font (or mathematical typography where feasible) for mathematical calculations and code font for computed things. So 1.0/100 or 1/100 is one-hundredth, and `1.0/100` is the computed result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I didn't go looking for a canonical Q&A about rounding to a certain number of decimal digits.  Good point about `nearbyint(x*100)/100.0` potentially having more than 0.5 ulp of total rounding error.  I wonder if there's an efficient algorithm that gives a correctly-rounded result.

Comment: As for `1.0/100`, this is an assembly question so I'm going to weasel out of it by arguing that there's no implication of a C interpretation of that expression; it could be a rational number.  But really my choice of `1.0` instead of `1/100` was based on C interpretation of int vs. FP literals :P  I guess another way to put it is that `1.0/100` is inexact if computed with FP math.  Evaluating that expression would raise an FP inexact exception.

Comment: I expect the ideal round-to-decimal task involves much the same issues as convert-binary-to-decimal-for-printing and would use the same complicated algorithms except for restricted cases limited in some way(s), as by number of digits to round to or by magnitude of input.